# Comparing both function on If and Else

Tags: c

Got this question just now when I’m tried comparing my program to both of my classmates (2 of them), and the results is there results came early (about 2 sec). Note that I forget to use the clock() function.

On `if`/`else` condition, is using the ternary operator

```
(Condition) ? (True) : (False);
```

slower than using this?

```
if (condition) {
    (function if True) 
}else { 
    (function if False)
}
```

Comment: It’s up to the compiler but I would be surprised if you saw any difference.

Comment: Make sure you enable optimizations when you compile.  If enabled, then it's unlikely that you would see a performance difference between `?:` vs. `if-else`.

Comment: Compile both, check out the assembler differences.  The difference, if any, is likely to be "don't care" for most applications.

Comment: If the expressions `True` and `function if True` are the same, and the corresponding `False` expressions are the same too, then there's no difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in terms of speed. Use ternary conditional only if you want to type less.
See the following example:

```
void f1(int i) {
    int val = (i > 10) ? i * 5 : i * 10;
}

void f2(int i) {
    int val;
    if(i > 10){
        val = i * 5;
    }else{
        val = i * 10;
    }
}
```

See the compiler generated assembly for both the functions [here](https://godbolt.org/z/u46ig9). 
There is no difference.